# Incrementing Excel row in python

Tags: python, excel

So I have tried a few different ways to get this to work, none have prevailed.

```
worksheet.merge_range('B4:D4', testStr)
```

This is the function to merge cells in excel. I have this inside a loop and want to be able to increment the 4 based on the value in the loop.

```
i = 5
worksheet.merge_range("B'%s':D'%s'", testStr) % (i, i)
```

I have tried implementing it like this, but it throws back an error. I'm not sure what else to try, to get the row to change as the loop goes.

It doesnt work trying to use the first part as variables like

```
worksheet.merge_range(str(i)+":"+str(i), testStr)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have your operator in the wrong place:

```
i = 5
worksheet.merge_range("B'%s':D'%s'", testStr) % (i, i)
```

Should be:

```
i = 5
range = "B" + str(i) + ":D" + str(i)
worksheet.merge_range(range, testStr)
```

Comment: Now that it works, you can merge the snazzy % operator back in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of %s try %d for decimal number.

check this https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html

Comment: worksheet.merge_range("B'%d':Z'%d'", testStr) % (i,i)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\worksheet.py", line 85, in cell
_wrapper
    row_1, col_1 = xl_cell_to_rowcol(cell_1)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\utility.py", line 108, in xl_ce
ll_to_rowcol
    col_str = match.group(2)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
Exception Exception: Exception('Exception caught in workbook destructor. Explici
t close() may be required for workbook.',) in <bound method Workbook.__del__ of
<xlsxwriter.workbook.Workbook object at 0x02E17730>> ignored